# How to stylize taken from another site data

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I've taken data from another site through php code that looks like this:

```
$page = file_get_contents('website');
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$doc->validateOnParse = true;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($page);
echo $doc->textContent;
```

And I get data that looks like this

```
    string(185180) " [
{
    "Id": "50671661",
    "date": "2017-09-26T00:00:00+0000",
    "DEP": "JFK",
    "ARR": "BEG"
},
{
    "Id": "50671689",
    "date": "2017-09-26T00:00:00+0000",
    "DEP": "BEG",
    "ARR": "AUH"
},
{
    "Id": "50671663",
    "date": "2017-09-26T00:00:00+0000",
    "DEP": "BEG",
    "ARR": "LCA",
},
....
]"
```

**How can I stylize received data?**